# Purge command throws error after purging - Discord.js V13

Tags: discord.js, message, purge

I'm made a purge command which targets a particular member and deletes the given amount. The problem is it deletes the messages correctly while on completion it throws a unknown error. Help me fix it! Here's the code and its error

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Permissions } = require('discord.js');
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {
    description: 'purge command',
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        setTimeout(() => message.delete(), 3500);

        if (message.member.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.KICK_MEMBERS)) {

            let purgeMember = message.mentions.users.first()
            let amount = args[1]
            if (!purgeMember) return message.channel.send("Please Mention a Member to purge").then(msg => { setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 4000) })
            if (!amount) return message.channel.send("Please provide a valid number to purge").then(msg => { setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 4000) })
            if (isNaN(amount)) return message.channel.send("Please provide a valid number to purge").then(msg => { setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 4000) })
            if (amount > 99) return message.channel.send("I can delete upto 100 messages only").then(msg => { setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 4000) })

            let AllMessages = await message.channel.messages.fetch()
            let FilteredMessages = await AllMessages.filter(x => x.author.id === purgeMember.id)
            let deletedMessages = 0
            FilteredMessages.forEach(msg => {
                if (deletedMessages >= amount) return
                msg.delete()
                deletedMessages++
            })

        } else {
            message.channel.send('️ | You DONT have permission to use this command!').then(msg => { setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 5000) })
        }

    },
}
```

Error

```
   throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message
    at RequestHandler.execute (D:\STUFF\BOT\Passion-Bot-V13\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:298:13)
    V13\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Message.js:709:5) {
  method: 'delete',
  path: '/channels/886173223144792074/messages/886174452994437170',
  code: 10008,
  httpStatus: 404,
  requestData: { json: undefined, files: [] }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is thrown for a cached message which bot is unable to delete appearently ( maybe pinned?, maybe cached but non existant?) You could just supress this error via `try/catch`

```js
try {
  msg.delete()
} catch {}
```

Furthermore at the topmost part of your code there's a
`setTimeout(() => message.delete(), 3500);` (waiting 3.5 seconds before deleting the first message), when you loop through your messages it's highly likely that the particular message with the command is in the cache existing too, so either one of those would delete it.

My suggestion:

- Either use `try/catch` in your `msg.delete()` within the loop
  **OR**
- Remove the timeout on the initial `message.delete()`

Comment: This isn't likely to fix the problem as the developer has added two msg.delete() functions inside of the code, and when a message has already been deleted, you cannot delete a message again, therefore it throws that error.

Comment: Thanks for clarification of the OP Jeff although this would supress that error, since the message cache is unknown to the developer at the moment the command could be at the very last of the cache too!  and it may even take greater than 3,500 milliseconds to delete those messages at some point so `try/catch` would be the best approach here, although I've included what you meant to say! Thanks for suggesting this edit.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem you are encountering right now is when a message doesn't exist as every `DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message` just means that a message is likely to be deleted.

The code:

```
setTimeout(() => message.delete(), 3500);
```

Is the error to the problem:

```
            FilteredMessages.forEach(msg => {
                if (deletedMessages >= amount) return
                msg.delete()
                deletedMessages++
            })
```

If you see the msg.delete() in the middle of the forEach function, the message has **already** been deleted, therefore the setTimeout is rather obvious to cause a problem.

By removing `setTimeout(() => message.delete(), 3500);`, it'll most likely fix the problem.